# Eliminating part of arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Assume that we have a 100*4 array.

We also have a 100*1 array of 1 and 0. Assume there are n 1's.

We want to create a n*4 array from the 100*4 array, where we only include the columns for which the second array is a 1.

One way to do it is through a double for loop. Is there a simpler method?

So, We have

```
A = [ [ 332 44 33 22 33 55 33 211 .....
      [ 823 44 12 98 19 23 32 911 .....
      ....
      ....
    ]
```

and

```
 B = [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ....]
```

and we want

```
 C = [ [ 332 22 ...
       [ 823 98 ...
       ....
       ....
     ]
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419220/matlab-extract-submatrix-with-logical-indexing), I think you are looking for a form of logical indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
C = A(:, B==1 );
```

Comment: Concise, correct, and with a reference in case you don't understand the syntax +1.

Answer (score 1):

First you `repmat` the logical vector so that it has the exact same size as the matrix `A`.

```
idx2keep = repmat(b, [1 4]); % Or [4 1] depending on if it's a col or row vector
```

Then you can simply index them with

```
 B = A( idx2keep )
```

you can then make it into a column vector:

```
 B = B(:)
```

That should do the job. Next time please always post some code or notation so it's easier and clearer to answer this.

Comment: `repmat`? haven't you heard of `bsxfun`?

Comment: How would bsxfun be used in this situation?

Also, this solution does returns a 1x(4n) array instead of a 4xn array.